# Python converting xlsx to csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, file-conversion

I am trying to convert all xlsx files to csv files in a folder. It worked well in the past, but I am getting an error this time that leaves me no clue.

Here's my code:

```
excel_files = glob.glob('/*xlsx*')

for excel_file in excel_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    output = excel_file.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
    df.to_csv(output)
```

I have also tried the following line to make sure it's not the encoding issue:

```
df.to_csv(output, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

It converted around 1000 files, but the rest of the 7000 files kept getting the error:

```
KeyError: 'rId6'
```

How would you solve it? Thank you.

Comment: your data is at fault, not the massive converting. Isolate one file that doesn't work and check it.

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: I would suggest comparing a working file against the files that did not work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How would you check which file doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: @Niels The problem is I don't even know which file doesn't work. It converted the files in a random order even I set a for loop of converting the files according to their file names.

Comment: catch the exception, and print the name of the currently processed file when there's an exception.

Comment: @StephenRauch Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind for my next questions. But in this case, I'm just converting all the xlsx files into csv files. What I asked should have already been the most minimal, complete and verifiable imho. But as said, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: But you're not getting an answer to this question, because nobody can answer it unless they can somehow _guess_ what's in your data files. So, assuming you need to solve this, don't just keep that advice in mind for future questions, apply it to this question, gather the information, and edit it in, so someone can help you.

Comment: @abarnert Understood. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh yes, Thanks a lot! I found those files that I think they were corrupted when being downloaded. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your files are badly formatted in some way. You should add exception handling to your loop, this would allow the conversions to continue and would indicate which of your files are causing the problem:

```
excel_files = glob.glob('/*xlsx*')

for excel_file in excel_files:
    print("Converting '{}'".format(excel_file))
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
        output = excel_file.split('.')[0]+'.csv'
        df.to_csv(output)    
    except KeyError:
        print("  Failed to convert")
```

You could then try opening the failing files inside Excel to see if they load ok. If they do load, you could upload an example of a failing Excel file to something like pastebin and add a comment here with the link to it so the problem can be recreated.